# macOS - Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/extglob/lib/.DS_Store?

Tags: macos

I was installing the **starship** via **homebrew**, but I am getting this error:

```
Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/extglob/lib/.DS_Store
```

Any solution for fixing this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Getting this error with sudo -> `Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.`

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can change owner by :

```
sudo chown -R ${LOGNAME}:staff /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: I have: ```zsh: bad substitution```

Comment: I solved my error, related with docker folder: `sudo chown -R ${LOGNAME}:staff /usr/local/lib/docker`. Thanks.

Comment: Solved my problem

Answer (score 379):

This issue appeared after upgrading macOS to **Mojave 10.14.X onwards**.

Therefore, you need to reset the permissions in **/usr/local**:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/* \
&& sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/*
```

Source: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/45009#issuecomment-543795948

Comment: I'd encountered this error while running `brew reinstall gcc` after a recent upgrade to bigSur. This solution provided at least an initial fix which got me onto the next error (which then required that I install Command Line Tools for Xcode 12 beta 3).

Comment: Shouldn't your chmod use rwX (with an upper-case X) as the perm symbol? The way you state the command, every single file will become group-executable. What is needed is every directory and previously-x-ed file to have the executable / directory search bit set, so X is prefered.

Comment: should there be a user called `admin`?

Comment: Just noting that running these commands may take some time (~1 minute for me) and has no progress bar

Comment: This worked beautifully AND it explained the core underlying issue.

Comment: This helped in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 60):

If you are getting the above error during brew cleanup “Permission denied @ apply2files”, one of the solutions which worked in my case was to reset permissions to `/usr/local`. You will have to rewrite permission to the current user. In your terminal copy and paste:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/* \
&& sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/*
```

Then rerun the command. The permission error should go.

Hope it may help someone in the future. Good luck

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, and the solutions suggested didn't fix it. I had to change the ownership of homebrew folder and subfolders

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /opt/homebrew/*`

Answer (score 2):

Change permission of the node_modules directory by running

```
sudo chown -R ${LOGNAME}:staff /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Answer (score 2):

first

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/* \
&& sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/*
```

the reinstall all the packages with

```
brew list --formula | xargs brew reinstall
```

this part may take few minutes but worked great for me

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command:
`sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/extglob/lib/.DS_Store`

Answer (score 1):

for me, the issue was with the permission of homebrew while cleaning the old packages `brew cleanup`

`sudo chown -R ${LOGNAME}:staff /opt/homebrew/lib/`

Answer (score 1):

For latest version of MacOS, I cannot use `*` to match subdirectories' patterns, zsh reports error:

```bash
➜  ~ sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/* \
&& sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/*
chown: /usr/local/*: No such file or directory
```

So instead, you can simply use ls to find subdirectories and send to `chown`:

```bash
cd /usr/local
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin `ls` \
&& sudo chmod -R g+rwx `ls`
```

Wait for a while and the operation shall succeed.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

Remove and reinstall `brew`.

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It works with

```
sudo chown -R douglas.mesquita:admin /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked with:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/python3.11/*
```

Answer (score -1):

what worked for me, simply delete the directory with

```
sudo rm -rf %error file path%
```

Comment: In my case the folder giving an error was not important so deleting it, fixed the problem. In general this is a bit dangerous as a fix